# Deployed beanstalk multi container application not reachable

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've succesffuly deployed a multi container docker image (with only one image in order to get started) in a beanstalk web based environment:

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 2,
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "name": "myApp",
      "image": "ecr-registry/myApp:latest",
      "memory": 512,
      "essential": true,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 8080,
          "containerPort": 9000
        }
      ],
      "environment": [
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

All beanstalk logs extracted show that everything's fine.

My app logs its successfully startup at port 9000.

Beanstalk docker ps logs shows my container has started

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                                                     COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
3638439d8678        ecr-registry/myApp:latest   "/bin/sh -c ./bin/ruâ€¦"   30 seconds ago      Up 29 seconds       0.0.0.0:8080->9000/tcp   <ecs random name>
```

Everything looks fine but I couldn't access my resource through http://beanstalk_host/path

I've already tried:

```
http://beanstalk_host:8080/path
```

```
http://ec2-ip:8080/path
```

```
http://beanstalk_host/path
```

The response is always "**Could not get any response**". I've already removed "hostPort":8080 port mapping in order to let beastalk create a random port but no success as well.

I could successfully access my endpoint http://beanstalk_host/path when I changed my multi-container to single container json configuration:

```
{
    "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
    "Image": {
        "Name": "ecr-registry/myApp:latest",
        "Update": "true"
    },
    "Ports": [
        {
            "ContainerPort": "9000"
        }
    ]
}
```

I can also successfully run my application locally using the following docker compose:

```
version: '3'
services:
  myService:
    build: .
    image: ecr-registry/myApp:latest
    container_name: myApp
    ports:
      - 8080:9000
```

I'd like to run my multicontainer configuration but no success.

Who has experienced something similar?

Answer (score 0):

I've just found the problem.

Elastic Beanstalk allows 2 Docker deployment types: Single Container and Multi Container. Both environments have its deployments triggered by Dockerrun.aws.json upload.

- The ec2 instance running Single Container applications starts an nginx instance listening on port 80 (**ps U root | grep nginx** got it) and redirects the requests to a random docker hostPort port which is generated at the ec2 instance startup. That's why Single Containers deployments don't need specify hostPort in Dockerrun.aws.json file and a simple port 80 call redirects the client to the required resources.
- The ec2 instance running Multi Container applications DOESN'T start nginx. It enforces us define the *hostPort* property in Dockerrun.aws.json file. And should be the same port as configured in my environment ec2 security group. This time I don't have nginx's aid. As my Dockerrun.aws.json hostPort property was 8080 I couldn't access my restful endpoints. The problem was solved changing my Dockerrun file as follows:

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 2,
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "name": "restql-http-easysim",
      "image": "010984114721.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/restql-http-easysim:latest",
      "memory": 512,
      "essential": true,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 80,   <----- this one was changed
          "containerPort": 9000
        }
      ],
      "environment": [
        { "name": "restql-config-file", "value": "restql.yml" },
        { "name": "PORT", "value": "9000" }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Bye